# Password Checking

Tags: java, md5

I have a website that once registered, you are meant to login.  To login, the php code checks to see if the password is correct by doing this:

```
       $subuser = stripslashes($subuser);
       $result = $database->confirmUserPass($subuser, md5($subpass));
```

$subuser is the username the user enters while logging in.
$subpass is the password the user enters while logging in.

Now the php code encrypts the password given($subpass) and checks the database to see if the encryptions match.

Now the problem here is:  I am currently making a java application that has a login form for the website built in.  I would like the java code to do the same thing as the php code does.  I have read multiple places and i still dont understand what to do.  Here is the java code so far:

```
String password = "pass";
        try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(password.getBytes(), 0, password.length());
        System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(32));

        } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I run this code in java, it is meant to give me the same encrypted string as it does in PHP, but the problem is that it doesn't... :(  Does any one know what i am doing wrong/missed out?  Thanks

If anymore info is needed, just ask me and i will hopefully edit this post and include the additional details.

Comment: Don't use `md5`. It is weak.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957024/convert-password-encryption-from-java-to-php?rq=1

Comment: use sha1 or custom encryption

Comment: I use md5 as thats the only one i can use at the moment.

Comment: Don't do it this way! You must use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29

Comment: Kan, im going to change it a bit later, thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the 4th and 5th line to

```
md.update(password.getBytes());
System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This worked and i am getting the same results :)

Comment: I can only do that in 6 mins, ill do that in 6 mins.  How can i give rep?

Comment: you need to click on the arrow pointing up on the left of the answer.

Comment: Thank you, Ill do that in a few minutes.